# Register multiple admin to django

Tags: django, geodjango

Here is my admin.py file. How do I add admin.OSMGeoAdmin to admin.site.register in addition to BikeAdmin?

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from models import Bike, RideInfo

class BikeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RideInfo
    extra = 1

class BikeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BikeInline]

admin.site.register(Bike,BikeAdmin) #want to register admin.OSMGeoAdmin also
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from models import Bike, RideInfo

class BikeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RideInfo
    extra = 1

class BikeAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    inlines = [BikeInline]

admin.site.register(Bike,BikeAdmin)
```

Comment: yes! This worked. I had a feeling I needed to let BikeAdmin inherit  OSMGeoAdmin but didn't know how to do that